# AWS - Stack creation - How to assign an inline policy to adhoc user?

Tags: security, aws, access-control

## Background:

With cross account role `someaccountrole`, I have access to  aws account `xyz`.

---

*Case 1*

To create a stack in account `xyz`, we upload the Cloudformation file through console.

Amidst stack creation in `Events` tab, we see the very first event, as shown below:

### [image]

---

*Case 2*

We create EC2 instance in `xyz` account.

Using [sam deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html), where `sam deploy` is a wrapper of `aws cloudformation deploy`, we run below command from EC2, for stack creation:

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file cfntemplate.yml --stack-name somestack-test --region us-east-1`

Amidst stack creation, we see the similar event created (as shown below):

### [image]

---

In case 2, user is: `arn:aws:sts::${AccountId}:assumed-role/Autodeploy/i-0000000cc4`. `Autodeploy` is the name of role assigned to EC2. This user disappears after stack creation is complete.

---

But in **case 2**, user(`i-0000000cc4`) need permission to perform following operations, unlike **case 1**:

```
     {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:CreateUploadBucket",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:${AccountId}:stack/somestack*”
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
```

otherwise, `Events` tab gives below error in case 2:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::${AccountId}:assumed-role/Autodeploy/i-0000000cc4 
is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource:
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:${AccountId}:stack/somestack-test
```

---

1) In case 1, permissions are not required for stack creation. but in case 2, Why stack creation through AWS CLI require stack creation permission?

2) How to assign an inline policy(short living) to such temporary session resource(`i-0000000cc4`) instead to an EC2??

Comment: Are you sure permissions are not required for stack creation in case #1?  What is the policy attached to *someaccountrole*?  What is the policy attached to the EC2 instance role?  Maybe the *someaccountrole* has perms to create a stack while the EC2 instance role does not.

Comment: @MacGruber ok let us say, `someaccountrole` has permissions to create stack that EC2 role doesn't. I will verify this tomorrow... probably you are right, but I will check the policies tomorrow under `someaccountrole`.

Comment: @MacGruber for my second question, how to assign policy to adhoc user? that is created amidst stack creation. Yes EC2 role does not have permissions to perform stack creation, but we don't want to give permissions at EC2 level. We prefer giving permission at user level, because we use that EC2 for different reasons

Comment: I'm not as familiar with CloudFormation since I generally use Terraform.  However, this idea of creating an ad-hoc user, one that only exists during the execution of the stack, seems a bit strange to me.  Also, why are you executing the _aws cloudformation_ command from the EC2 instance?  I would think you should execute it from your workstation/laptop with the proper credentials (i.e an IAM role that you can assume that has just enough perms required for the CloudFormation stack deploy).

Comment: @MacGruber executing aws cloudformation is part of jenkins pipeline...

Comment: In that case, within the Jenkins pipeline you should assume a role with permissions to deploy a CloudFormation stack.

Comment: @MacGruber  Within jenkins pipeline, assuming role? you mean EC2 hosting jenkins should assume a role? i did not get you.... Do you mean? https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy

Comment: No, what I mean is using the _aws sts assume-role..._ CLI from within the Jenkins pipeline.  That will give you temporary credentials for the role which you can use for the life of the pipeline, as long as the pipeline doesn't exceed the max session duration.  Also, be sure to specify a duration for the temporary token with the _--duration-seconds_.  It defaults to 15 minutes, not the max duration.